# problema con el contenedor del texto

Tags: html, css

[image]

buenas mi problemas es que cuando reduzco navegador la letras se salen de la imagen y no se como arreglarlo.

Comment: Usa una media query para reducir el tamaño de la letra cuando la resolución es pequeña y problema arreglado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de pixels, rems, etc usa vw (viewport width). Esto es: un font size de 3vw va a ser el 3% del ancho de la caja contenedora, a medida que esa caja se achique (dispositivos moviles por ejemplo) la font lo hara tambien porque es un porcentaje y no una medida fija. Pon esta linea en tu html y encoge el navegador en ancho y veras como la letra se adapta

```
 <div style="font-size: 10vw">HOLA MUNDO!!</div>
```